# Comparator for groups of types

Tags: java, comparator

I would like to sort array of objects. Each object has `getType()` method which returns object type in String.

I would like to sort my array depending on the type with something like priorities.

Example:

```
Input { A, F, Z, G, E, D, C }

If(type == A or B or C or D) top 
If(type == E) second
If(type == F or G) third
If(differet type) last

Output: { A, C, D, E, F, G, Z }
```

How should my comparator look like ?

If I haven't stated my question clear enough, please write a comment, I'll try to explain more briefly the part which is not clear.

Comment: is `type` a string value

Comment: Why does your output start { A, C, D }? Could it just as easily be { D, A, C }? i.e. are all elements within your groups effectively equal? What have you tried?

Comment: Are all your objects of the same class or do they at least inherit off of the same interface / class? Or are they all different classes (each type representing a different class)?

Comment: Jon Skeet, the output sequance doesn't matter to me. It may be { A, C, D } or it may be { D, A, C }. Both are correct for me. All the objects in array are the same type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a priorities hash map:

```
private static final HashMap<String,Integer> PRIORITIES = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
static{
    PRIORITIES.put("A", 1);
    PRIORITIES.put("B", 1);
    PRIORITIES.put("C", 1);
    PRIORITIES.put("D", 1);
    PRIORITIES.put("E", 2);
    PRIORITIES.put("F", 2);
    PRIORITIES.put("G", 3);
}
```

Then implement `compare` method of your `Comparator`:

```
private int getPriority(CustomClass obj) {
    if(obj!=null&&PRIORITIES.containsKey(obj.getType())) {
        priority1 = PRIORITIES.get(obj.getType());
    } else {
        priority1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}

@Override
public int compare(CustomClass o1, CustomClass o2) {
    int priority1,priority2;
    priority1 = getPriority(o1);
    priority2 = getPriority(o2);
    return priority1==priority2 ? 0 : (priority1<priority2 ? -1 : 1);
}
```

**UPDATE:** Cleaner approach is to define hashmap in your base class (where `getType` is declared) and to implement `getPriority` method:

```
public int getPriority() {
    return PRIORITIES.containsKey(getType()) ? PRIORITIES.get(getType()) : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Then `Comparator` is obvious:

```
@Override
public int compare(CustomClass o1, CustomClass o2) {
    int priority1,priority2;
    priority1 = o1==null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : o1.getPriority();
    priority2 = o2==null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : o2.getPriority();
    return priority1==priority2 ? 0 : (priority1<priority2 ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Comment: I have found, your answer most usefull. Thank you for your time looking into my answer and sharing your knowledge !

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
class Comparer implements Comparator<YourType>
{
   @Override
   public int compare(YourType o1, YourType o2)
   {
      return Integer.compare(getRank(o1), getRank(o2));
      // Pre-Java 7
      //Integer v1 = getRank(o1);
      //return v1.compareTo(getRank(o2));
   }

   int getRank(YourType o)
   {
      switch (o.getType())
      {
         case "A": case "B": case "C": case "D":
            return 1;
         case "E":
            return 2;
         case "F": case "G":
            return 3;
         default:
            return 4;
      }
   }
}
```

Then:

```
YourType[] arr = ...;
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparer());
```

The above will only work in Java 7 and up because `switch` on `String` is not supported before Java 7.

If you're not running Java 7, you'll have to use if-statements instead of the `switch`.

Comment: Your answer is correct, yet I think default locale aproach is better, so I will accept his answer. But thank you for your time and usefull answer as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have your objects `Comparable<ElementType>` interface (since they are all of the same class (lets say `ElementType`  and the call `Arrays.sort(myArray)`. If you want to sort the object using different a different order each time, then you should create a `Comparator` object

You can see nice examples [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using [Guava's](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html) `Ordering` class to make sort the input for you. If the objects you are dealing with have the notion of a "natural" order, then you can do something like `Ordering<Input>.natural` or implement your own comparator inside of the instantiation:

```
Ordering<Input> getInputOrder = new Ordering<Input>() {
 public int compare(Input A, Input B) {
   return A.comparableMember > B.comparableMember
 }
};
```